# a problem on normal approximation to the poisson - from Durrett's book

Tags: probability

I came across a problem from Durrett's book *Elementary Probability*

> P.217 Example 6.26
>
> **Normal approximation to the Poisson**. Each year inMythica, an average of 25 letter carriers are bitten by dogs. In the past year, 33 incidents were reported. Is this number exceptionally high?
>
> **Solution:** Assuming that dog bites are a rare event, we use the Poisson distribution for the number of dog bites. As we observed in Example 6.3, a Poisson with mean 25 is the sum of 25 independent Poisson mean 1 random variables, so we can use the normal to approximate the Poisson.
>
> The mean is $25$, while the standard deviation is $\sqrt{25} = 5$.Writing the observed event as $≥32.5$ we see that this is $(32.5−25)/5 = 1.5$ standard deviations above the mean, so the normal approximation is $$P(\chi ≥ 1.25) = 1 − 0.8943 = 0.1057$$so this is not a very unusual event.

Why it is $P(\chi ≥ 1.25)$, not $P(\chi ≥ 1.5)$? Can anybody explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because even very good books can have typos. The number of typos in a page is often modeled using the Poisson distribution.

Comment: which, under some mild condition, you can approximate with a normal distribution!

Comment: But $P(\chi ≥ 1.5) = 1- 0.9332 = 0.0668$, so it's less likely to be just typos

Comment: "Typo" is sometimes used as a polite word for "minor slip," which is itself sometimes a polite term for "mistake."

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Aha, I see